# Insert or update rows in second table based on rows from first table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. I must insert or update second table, based on records from first table and `INVE_KEY`, `EVEN_KEY` (combination of both must be unique).

First table = @tbl1

Second table = @tbl2

Example 1:

> If second table alredy has INVE_KEY=1,EVEN_KEY=2, and first table has
>   INVE_KEY=1,EVEN_KEY=2, than this row will be only updated in second table (column
>   QUA).

Example 2:

> If second table doesn't have INVE_KEY=3,EVEN_KEY=1, then this row will
>   be inserted into second table from first table.

My problem is that I don't know how to do insert from table to table and at the same time check if each record exists in second table?

First table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
| INVE_KEY | EVEN_KEY | QUA |
+----------+----------+-----+
|        1 |        1 |   3 |
|        2 |        1 |   4 |
|        3 |        1 |   5 |
|        4 |        1 |   6 |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Second table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
| INVE_KEY | EVEN_KEY | QUA |
+----------+----------+-----+
|        3 |        1 |   0 |
|        4 |        1 |   0 |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

After updating second table, expected result:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
| INVE_KEY | EVEN_KEY | QUA |
+----------+----------+-----+
|        1 |        1 |   3 |(inserted)
|        2 |        1 |   4 |(inserted)
|        3 |        1 |   5 |(updated QUA)
|        4 |        1 |   6 |(updated QUA)
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Creation and data for both tables:

```
declare @tbl1 table
          (
            INVE_KEY INT,
            EVEN_KEY INT,
            QUA INT
          )

          declare @tbl2 table
          (
            INVE_KEY INT,
            EVEN_KEY INT,
            QUA INT
          )


          insert into @tbl1(inve_Key, even_Key, qua)
          values(1, 1, 3),(2,1,4),(3,1,5),(4,1,6)

          insert into @tbl2(inve_Key, even_Key, qua)
          values(3,1,0),(4,1,0)
```

Comment: Do it in 2 statements. First --> update existing records (try to google for the UPDATE FROM syntax); Second --> Insert missing records

Comment: Why not just truncate the second table first and then just populate the whole table with the expected result from first table.

Comment: Have you looked at MERGE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: @AnkitBajpai that would be ok with only 4 rows but that approach is not going to scale well. And if there is an identity in the table you can't truncate it.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - perhaps you have example on this?

Comment: @Sean Lange, As far as I know truncate would reset the Identity seed to 1. If we need to store the identity counter `Delete' is preferred.

Comment: I didn't mean you can't truncate it. Yes of course we can truncate when there is an identity. But dropping all the data to repopulate it is not going to scale well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
  MERGE INTO TargetTable AS TargetTable
  USING SourceTable AS SourceTable
  ON (TargetTable.INVE_KEY = SourceTable.INVE_KEY) -- business keys only
     and (TargetTable.EVEN_KEY = SourceTable.EVEN_KEY)
  -- Insert the new rows
  WHEN NOT MATCHED --  New records 
  THEN
    INSERT ( INVE_KEY,
             EVEN_KEY,
             QUA

             )
    VALUES  
  (        SourceTable.INVE_KEY,
             SourceTable.EVEN_KEY,
-- Updates

  WHEN MATCHED AND ( TargetTable.QUA <> SourceTable.QUA
            ) THEN

    UPDATE SET  
  TargetTable.QUA = SourceTableQUA ;
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)Perhaps you have some good link on documentation for this?

Comment: It is not recommended to use MERGE statements. It is better to use INSERT/UPDATE instead of that. MERGE syntax is quite hard and it has some number of the not fixed bugs. In other way it doesn't benefit in performance for the most cases

Comment: Do you have any better proposal? All I can think about is cursor, which is for sure worse than merge. If not merge, I would use cursor instead. Can you show code for that particular example not using merge, please?